# Find by field in JpaRepository, genrated sql looks weird and can not get result from DB

Tags: spring-boot, groovy, spring-data-jpa

`User` written in java

```
package com.peini.backend.entity;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.ToString;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import javax.persistence.*;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

@Data
@Entity
@Component
@ToString
@Table(name = "user")
@Embeddable
public class User implements Serializable{
  private static final long serialVersionUID = -1L;
  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  @Column(name = "id")
  private Long id;

  @NotBlank
  @Column(name = "user_name")
  @Size(min = 3, max = 80)
  private String userName;

  @Email
  @Column(name = "email",unique = true)
  @Size(min = 5, max = 80)
  private String email;

  @Column(name = "password")
  @Size(min = 6, max = 20)
  private String password;

  @Column(name = "registered_time")
  @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
  private Date registeredDate;
}
```

this is user entity

```
package com.peini.backend.dao

import com.peini.backend.entity.User
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository

@Repository
interface AccountDao extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

  User findByEmail(String email);
}
```

This is dao, writen in groovy,  I want to get user by email, but the sql in console looks weird, like this:

```
Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_0_, user0_.email as email2_0_, user0_.password as password3_0_, user0_.registered_time as register4_0_, user0_.user_name as user_nam5_0_ from user user0_ where user0_.email=?.
```

the property name is wrong,and can not get result from mysql database, so what can I do or modify?

Comment: 'id1_0_', 'email2_0_' and others are Hibernate-generated aliases. Where clause 'where user0_.email=?' seems OK. The request works as intended - finds and returns User by email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually fine. Hibernate just uses specific aliases, but if you carefully look at the query, you'll see that it aliases `user` as `user0_`. Additionally to that, it also maps all field to an alias like `id1_0_`, `email2_0_`, ... .

However, if you strip those aliases, you can see it uses a proper query:

```sql
select id, email, password, registered_time, user_name from user where email=?
```

The reason why Hibernate does this is to be able to link those fields back to their entities by generating unique aliases for each field.

> **NOTE**: The code responsible for generating these aliases is [`Column.getAlias()`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/orm/javadocs/org/hibernate/mapping/Column.html#getAlias-org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect-org.hibernate.mapping.Table-). For tables/entities it uses [`StringHelper.generateAlias()`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/javadocs/org/hibernate/internal/util/StringHelper.html#generateAlias-java.lang.String-int-).

This is, however, not a problem. So if you're not getting the results you want, you have an error elsewhere, and not within the query.

Comment: yeah, It's ok with findByUserName, I also don't know where is findByEmail  wrong